# Let A = {a, {∅}}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are the following True/False

{a} is a subset of A (I believe this is true since every element of {a} is in A)

{{∅}} is a subset of A - I am confused here

Comment: Run the same process that you did with $\{a\}$. What are the elements of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$?

Answer (score 2):

Don't think about the meaning of $\{\emptyset\}$ as a set. Think about it as an element of $A$. You could just call $z=\{\emptyset\}$, and basically the set $A$ will be rewritten as $A=\{a,z\}$ so the statement can be understood as "$\{z\}$ is a subset of $A$", just like the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\{\phi\}$ is an element of $A$ so when you say $\{\{\phi\}\}$ this means this is the set containing the element $\{\phi\}$ inside it and thus, the set $\{\{\phi\}\}$ is a subset of $A$ since the element $\{\phi\}$ is also found in $A$.